# Twitter timeline - How to include retweets?

Tags: json, twitter

This loads up a Twitter feed and displays the last tweet.

Is there a way to include and retrieve all the retweets in this function?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = "http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/mytwittername.json?count=3&callback=?";
    var lastClass = "";
    $.getJSON(url,
        function(data){
            $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            // check for last tweet
            if (i == (data.length - 1)) {
                lastClass = "class='last'"
            }
            $("#twitter-content ul").append("<li " + lastClass + ">" + item.text.linkify().atify() + " <span class='created_at'>[" + relative_time(item.created_at) + " via " + item.source + "]</span></li>");
        });
    });

    $("#sidebar ul li:last-child").addClass("last");
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modify the `url` variable in your code to be the following:

```
http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/mytwittername.json?count=3&include_rts=1&callback=?
```

The magic is in the `include_rts=1` parameter which will cause retweets by the target user to be included in their timeline.

The [statuses/user_timeline](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/user_timeline) method does not require authentication, however if you do auth, you'll get an extra 200 API calls per hour. Note that the `twitter.com` REST methods are no longer supported, so be sure to use the versioned API methods when interacting with Twitter.

Comment: This is the correct answer. However, as of 2012-10-05, Twitter seems to be ignoring the "include_rts" param.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here:

[https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/retweets/:id](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/retweets/%3Aid)

In your loop if you had the id of the original tweet then you could probably get the retweet as well.

I haven't tried it, but this is what I found.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link Jeff, will give this a try!

Comment: It just didn't work?  Did it give you an error?  What did it do?

Comment: It wouldn't parse the retweets for some reason. Looking into the API, I need to setup authentication too... still trying at it.